# is it possible for a web game(in this case Mr.Mine) to not use a TCP port at all to run itself?

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I'm playing Mr.Mine web game and I was struggling to find a way that will do the 'selling' automatically for me.

Based on some helpful guidance from stackoverflow, I started to search for a packet that does the 'selling' part of the game.

Maybe its because of my lack of knowledge and skills but I just cannot find any packets that seem to be related to mr.mine

I tried analyzing it with Wireshark, windows network monitor, TCPView.

The funny thing is, whenever I run these programs and click the 'sell' button in the game, there is no movement in the packet capture list related to chrome.exe.

I've checked if there are any newly opened ports when I press button in the game with TCPView but there was no changes in ports.

I find this weird because if this is a web game, shouldn't clicking the buttons in the game send out a packet to the server?

One theory that I came up with myself if that perhaps all the game operations are done inside my computer. I've had a brief look on the html source code([view-source](http://mrmine.com/)) of the web game and it was full of javascripts.

But still.. no movement in tcp ports or packets?

So here's my final question. Is it possible for a web game to function with out opening its own TCP port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So here's my final question. Is it possible for a web game to function with out opening its own TCP port?

Yes. As long as all logic is done locally and all assets are loaded, there's no need for additional downloads or server communication. After all, the JavaScript code is already on your machine, your browser executes it, and your actions modify the state saved on *your* PC.

Comment: thanks but I have another question. In the game there is this 'save' function. So is this also done within my computer thereby not needing an internet connection? Wouldn't this mean that I can just hack into the game and make modify my data? ... I mean.. then why does this game need an internet connection in the first place??

Comment: @kwagjj: Cookies. And the internet connection is needed for the first data download.

Comment: hmm.. thanks for giving me a new lead to work on. One more question if you don't mind... since this game operates in javascript, is there a way to somehow inject an mouseclick event handler that will automatically click the 'sell' button repeatedly? Have you ever heard of this sort of 'injection'?

Comment: @kwagjj: Injecting mouse events is cumbersome. Better copy the function that gets called in that case and use `setInterval`. Use your browser's JavaScript console (`setInterval(button.onclick, 300);`). Yes, I've heard of it, some Students at my University change their amount of cookies in cookie clicker.